# d3 clipPath - why is it cutting top of charts off?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, clip

I have a graphic with three line graphs on it.

I've added a single clipPath to the chart, covering all three line graphs. But the top of each line chart is being chopped off.

I've added .nice() to the y axes, based on other SO answers, which has helped but not fixed the problem. When you zoom in with the time widget, the effect is very obvious: at the highest point of the line, the 2px line is being thinned. Getting rid of the attribute for clip-path returns the lines to their proper effect.

```
cG.append("path")
    .attr("class","line line1")
    .attr("stroke",palette.basic[0])//predicted
    .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
    .attr("d",line1[q](pricesPredicted));
```

Does anyone know why this is happening or how to stop it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `clipPath` and the elements you are clipping are not defined in the same coordinate system and are not subject to the same transforms.

All 3 charts are drawn starting from the top left corner. Imagine them all drawn on top of each other.

Then, the `clipPath` is applied and the charts are cut off.

Finally the charts are translated to their place.

Here's an example:

```html
<svg>
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clipPath">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>

  <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="20" style="clip-path: url(#clipPath);" transform="translate(10 10)" />
</svg>
```

You should try and apply the same transform to the `clipPath` that you are applying to your charts.