# IOS app webview SVG ClipPath Issue

Tags: javascript, ios, d3.js, svg

I'm using `d3 v4` to render SVG graphics. I'm using a [clipPath](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/clipPath) on a few `<path>` elements. I have panning behavior on a rect element and the clipPath is helping hide some of the path elements. When panning over in android. The clipPath works as necessary, but when panning in iOS the drawing is rendering funky. See below:

**BEFORE**

[image: BEFORE]

**AFTER**
[image: AFTER PANNING]

I've implemented the SVG clip with the following code:

```
   this.line = d3.line()
    .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX)
    .x((d) => this.xScale(this.getDate(d)))
    .y((d) => this.yScale(d.kWh));

this.area = d3.area()
    .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX)
    .x((d) => {
        return this.xScale(this.getDate(d))
    })
    .y0(this.height)
    .y1((d) => this.yScale(d.kWh));

// Definition for clipPath
this.svg.append("defs").append("clipPath")
    .attr("id", "clip")
    .append("rect")
    .attr("width", this.width)
    .attr('transform', 'translate(0,-20)')
    .attr("height", this.height + 20);
// clipPath added to area
var areaPath = this.focus.append("path")
    .datum(this.data)
    .attr("class", "area")
    .attr('height', this.height)
    .attr('fill-opacity', .2)
    .attr('clip-path', 'url(#clip)')
    .attr("d", this.area)
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + 80 + ")")
    .style("fill", "url(#gradient)");
// clipPath added to the line
var linePath = this.focus.append('path')
    .datum(this.data)
    .attr('class', 'line')
    .attr('fill', 'none')
    .attr('clip-path', 'url(#clip)')
    .attr('stroke', '#31B5BB')
    .attr('stroke-width', '2px')
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + 80 + ")")
    .attr('d', this.line);
```

He are excerpts from the zoom that is called on zoom.

```
    private zoomed = () => {

        if (this.isMinZooming) return;

        let diff,
            domain,
            minBuffer,
            maxBuffer,
            t;

        t = d3.event.transform;
        // loose mobile events
        if (isNaN(t.k)) return;

        this.xScale.domain(t.rescaleX(this.x2Scale).domain());
        diff = this.daydiff(this.xScale.domain()[0], this.xScale.domain()[1]);

        // Redraw Axis
        this.xAxis = d3.axisBottom(this.xScale).tickSize(0).tickFormat(d3.timeFormat('%b'));
        this.focus.select(".axis--x").call(this.xAxis);

        // Redraw Paths. This is where the redraw function gets messy in the iOS webview.
        this.focus.select(".area").attr("d", this.area);
        this.focus.select('.line').attr('d', this.line);

        ...
}
```

Has anyone had the same issue when using the clipPath?

Comment: I would say this is due to the fact that the clipPath and the elements you are clipping are not defined in the same coordinate system and are not subject to the same transforms http://stackoverflow.com/a/38088473/1160916

Comment: @Ashitaka why would this work for every browser but IOS? it even works in safari. Do you have any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue. It is such a suddle bug. I was defining somewhere in my css file:

```
.area{
   clip-path: url(#clip);
}
```

In all browsers this would work for `<rect>` and `<path>`, but for the `iOS webview` it would render the above display error.

Instead defining this in a separate  `CSS` file, I defined it inline for all `SVG Object` that I wanted to apply it to as such:

```
  var areaPath = this.focus.append("path")
        ...
        .attr('clip-path', 'url(#clip)') //defining it inline
```

This bug drove me crazy, but I'm glad I've found the solution.